# Fixing really ugly shadows

Tags: lighting, shadows

I'm quite new to Blender. I try to create a cloth model but the shadows that I get are really weird and ugly. I tried to use a "Subdivision Surface" modifier but it doesn't help. Does anybody know what is the source of my problem and how to fix it? Thank you in advance.
I include my project file:
[image]

[image: render]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of your topology, there are probably some coplanar faces that make some folds look flat when you wanted them to be round, maybe you've subdivided with no smoothness for example, you should have put the *Smoothness* value at 1, or even better, you should have subdivided with the *Subdivision Surface* modifier, it would have given a rounder result.

To fix your problem you can select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Un-Subdivide*, and give it a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, or give your object one of the *Smooth* modifiers, like the *Smooth Corrective*, and apply:

[image]

To be more clear, if you have a cube that has a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, here is how it will look like:

[image]

If you subdivide it with a right click > *Subdivide*, with no smoothness, it won't round the cube, on the contrary, as it adds edges in the middle of each face, it will tend to flatten these faces:

[image]

To avoid that, push the *Smoothness* of te subdivide operation up to 1:

[image]

For your flag, you probably subdivided with no smoothness.

Comment: There is also baked lighting that causes this bad black/red contrast when you render the image. Press the *Delete Lighting Cache* button in the *Render Properties* tab. Render engine must be set to Eevee to see this settings. After this, increase the power of the area light so you can see something (1 W is not enough).